# how to make SSH command execution to timeout

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ssh

I have a program like this:

```
ssh -q harigm@8.19.71.238 exit
echo "output value  -->$?"
```

In the above code, I am trying to SSH to the remote server, and tries to check if I can connect or not.
I have few servers, which is password less is activated and few servers for which passwords are still not yet deactivated.
So my concern, if there is a password, it will get stuck in the same screen asking for the password and it will be there for infinite time, without Exit logic.

Question : How to implement the timers for the above code, and if it stays in the same screen asking for the password. and exit with some error code

2) When I execute the above code, i get the following error codes:

```
127 -- > I guess its for success
225 -- > for any error.
```

are there any other error codes other than above?

Comment: http://www.eldos.com/documentation/sbb/documentation/ref_err_ssherrorcodes.html, found one link,

Comment: Don't bang out in case password is not supplied & key based auth is not setup.

Use expect scripts. (Search for ssh+expect on google/stackoverflow, for a template script.)

Comment: use -o PasswordAuthentication=no

Comment: Thanks @Vorsprung, password issue is resolved, if you have the info about the error codes of SSH command, please share

Comment: @gmhk - In FreeBSD, you can [`man sysexits`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits) to see the recommended exit codes for programs.  I don't know if they differ in other operating system.  Generally, an exit value of `0` means "success", and anything else is some kind of failure.

Comment: "ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occured" so if it worked, you get 0 from exit.  If it timed out or did any other error you get 255

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could wrap the call to `ssh` using the `timeout` command.  The `timeout` command exits with code 124 if a timeout occurs.

```
timeout 10s ssh -q harigm@8.19.71.238 exit
if [ $? -eq 124 ]; then
    echo "Timeout out"
fi
```

Or, as Vorsprung has commented on your question (as I was looking up the man page!):

```
ssh -oPasswordAuthentication=no -q harigm@8.19.71.238 exit
```

which will disallow interactive password authentication.  You'd then have to check the exit code.

Comment: ssh -oPasswordAuthentication=no -q harigm@8.19.71.238 exit --> this worked

Comment: @gmhk - don't forget to click the checkmark for the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the question is asking about 'batch mode' processing against a number of hosts at once (e.g., in a loop). The following `ssh` command will simply fail if PKA is *not* configured for a given host (public key authentication -- the "password-less" login mentioned the original question), so it is good for scripts that you just want to continue running regardless of problems connecting to one or two hosts.  It also won't bother with all the queries about "are you sure you want to continue connecting" to  previously unknown hosts (or you can just add `StrictHostKeyChecking no` to your `~/.ssh/config` for that).   For example,

```
for host in host1 host2 host3  # etc
do
  ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=5 \
      user@$host  'uptime' || echo "problem: host=$host"
done
```

You'll have to check your (client) `ssh` man page to see if these options (`BatchMode`, `ConnectTimeout`) are supported, though.

Comment: note that nowadays it's possible to use `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new` instead of `no`, for slightly better security.