# Optimistic way to test port before executing sftp

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sftp, aix

I have a bash script which is doing very plain sftp to transfer data to production and uat servers. See my code below.

```
  if [ `ls -1 ${inputPath}|wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
        sh -x wipprod.sh >> ${sftpProdLog}
        sh -x wipdev.sh >> ${sftpDevLog}
        sh -x wipdevone.sh >> ${sftpDevoneLog}
  fi
```

sometimes the UAT server may go down. In those cases the number of scripts hanged are getting increased. If it reaches the user max. number of process the other scripts also getting affected. So I am thinking before executing each of the above script i have to test the port 22 availability on the destination server. Then I can execute the script.

Is this the right way? If yes what is the optimistic way to do that? If no what else is the best approach to avoid unnecessary sftp connection when destination not available? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would rather have a timeout. If they try forever, there's something wrong.

Comment: ^^ Note however, that if you are suggesting the `timeout` command, then `scp` could take long time, depending on transfer size. TCP has a concept called `keepalive`. See if that can be used. Alternately, you can have a parallel script, which runs `ssh user@host true` periodically, & if it fails, then kill the `scp` script...

Comment: @anishsane I am not doing scp because I need to transfer files to multiple   path. So I don't want to initiate each as separate connection. If I use sftp, I can send multiple files to multiple path in single connection.

Comment: Ok, just mentally replace `scp` by `sftp` in above comment... :D

Answer (score 1):

Use sftp in batch mode together with ConnectTimeout option explicitely set. Sftp will take care about up/down problems by itself.
Note, that ConnectTimeout should be slightly higher if your network is slow.
Then put sftp commands into your wip*.sh backup scripts.

If UAT host is up:

```
[localuser@localhost tmp]$ sftp -b - -o ConnectTimeout=1 remoteuser@this_host_is_up <<<"put testfile.xml /tmp/"; echo $?
sftp> put testfile.xml /tmp/
Uploading testfile.xml to /tmp/testfile.xml
0
```

File is uploaded, sftp exits with exit code 0.

If UAT host is down, sftp **exits wihin 1 second** with exit code 255.

```
[localuser@localhost tmp]$ sftp -b - -o ConnectTimeout=1 remoteuser@this_host_is_down <<<"put testfile.xml /tmp/"; echo $?
ssh: connect to host this_host_is_down port 22: Connection timed out
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
255
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds reasonable - if the server is inaccessible you want to immediately report an error and not try and block.

The question is - why does the SFTP command block if the server is unavailable? If the server is down, then I'd expect the port open to fail almost immediately and you need only detect that the SFTP copy has failed and abort early.

If you want to detect a closed port in bash, you can simply as bash to connect to it directly - for example:

```
(echo "" > /dev/tcp/remote-host/22) 2>/dev/null || echo "failed"
```

This will open the port and immediately close it, and report a failure if the port is closed.

On the other hand, if the server is inaccessible because the port is blocked (in a firewall, or something, that drops all packets), then it makes sense for your process to hang and the base TCP test above will also hang.

Again this is something that should probably be handled by your SFTP remote copy using a timeout parameter, as suggested in the comments, but a bash script to detect blocked port is also doable and will probably look something like this:

```
(
  (echo "" > /dev/tcp/remote-host/22) & 
  pid=$!
  timeout=3
  while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null; do
    sleep 1
    timeout=$(( $timeout - 1 ))
    [ "$timeout" -le 0 ] && kill $pid && exit 1
  done
) || echo "failed"
```

Comment: Two notes: --- 1. `echo` will send a newline to the socket. If you want to just test if the TCP connection opens, use a command with no output fore example `true`. --- 2. On many systems there is the `timeout` utility so normally you do not need the killing script. Just do: `timeout 3 bash -c 'true > /dev/tcp/remote-host/22' || echo failed`

Answer (score 0):

(I'm going to ignore the `ls ...|wc` business, other than to say something like `find` and `xargs --no-run-if-empty` are generally more robust if you have GNU `find`, or possibly AIX has an equivalent.)

You can perform a runtime connectivity check, OpenSSH comes with `ssh-keyscan` to quickly probe an SSH server port and dump the public key(s), but sadly it doesn't provide a usable exit code, leaving parsing the output as a messy solution.

Instead you can do a basic check with a bash one-liner:

```
read -t 2 banner < /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/22
```

where `/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/22` (or `/dev/tcp/hostname/ssh`) indicates the host and port to connect to.

This relies on the fact that the SSH server will return an [identifying banner terminated with CRLF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-4.2). Feel free to inspect `$banner`. If it fails after the indicated timeout `read` will receive SIGALARM (exit code 142), and connection refused will result in exit code 1.

(Support for `/dev/tcp` and network redirection is enabled by default since before `bash-2.05`, though it can be disabled explicitly with `--disable-net-redirections` or with `--enable-minimal-config` at build time.)

To prevent such problems, an alternative is to set a timeout: with any of the `ssh`, `scp` or `sftp` commands you can set a connection timeout with the option `-o ConnectTimeout=15`, or, implicitly via `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host 1.2.3.4 myserver1
    ConnectionTimeout 15
```

The commands will return non-zero on timeout (though the three commands may not all return the same exit code on timeout). See this related question: [how to make SSH command execution to timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785832/how-to-make-ssh-command-execution-to-timeout)

Finally, if you have GNU `parallel` you may use its `sem` command to limit concurrency to prevent this kind of problem, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168978/limit-maximum-number-of-concurrent-scp-processes-running-on-a-host .